# Moving a gif with arrowkeys, causing error Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){throw"Ticker cannot be instantiated.";}

Tags: javascript, gif, createjs, arrow-keys

I am a beginner at javascript.  Like, REALLY beginner status.
My goal: I made a gif of a floating cat tied to a balloon.  I would like to be able to move the gif around on a canvas using the arrow keys.  Now, I have my gif on the canvas, and I can move it around with the arrow keys.  However, the gif moves frame-by-frame as you move the arrow keys.  I mean, it is a still gif until you move the arrow key once, then it advances by one frame.

If it is any help, here is my code:

```
<script>

var KEYCODE_LEFT = 37, 
    KEYCODE_RIGHT = 39,
    KEYCODE_UP = 38, 
    KEYCODE_DOWN = 40;
var myStage;
var floaty;

function keyPressed(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case KEYCODE_LEFT:  
            floaty.x -= 5;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_RIGHT: 
            floaty.x += 5; 
            break;
        case KEYCODE_UP: 
            floaty.y -= 5;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_DOWN: 
            floaty.y += 5;
            break;
    }
    myStage.update();
}

function init(){
    myStage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById("myCanvas"))
    floaty = new balloon();
    floaty.x = 300;
    floaty.y = 200;
    myStage.addChild(floaty);

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(6);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", drawNewFrame);
    }

function drawNewFrame(evt){ 
    myStage.update();
    }

function start(){
    this.document.onkeydown = keyPressed;
    }

</script>
```

And the body:

```
<body onload="init(); start();">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

This is the error that I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){throw"Ticker cannot be instantiated.";} has no method 'addEventListener'

I want the gif to run continuously, not just advancing by one frame.  I thought that "drawNewFrame" would get the gif to run continuously, but it isn't working.
I don't know what that error means.  If anyone could lend me some assistance in figuring out what that error means, I would really appreciate it. Thank you ^_^

Comment: What is `createjs`? What is `balloon`? What have you tried? Why should I do your homework?

Comment: I've done some digging around for you and found this cool code example, which may help you out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589516(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm doing it for my own project, not like it's an in-class assignment.  I'm going beyond the class, and got stuck.  I just didn't understand what the error meant.  

Balloon is the name of my gif.  Umm... I don't really know what createjs is.  I've been looking at code samples, and it was just there.

Comment: Oh, yes.  Don't worry, I have the createjs library included in my code (didn't know what it was called).  The code example is a little bit advanced for me, but I'll definitely take a look.  I'm sorry, I'm really just beginning to teach myself this.  I don't even know if I can get to my goal with the basic knowledge I have, or if I'll need some more education.

Comment: I think gif (animated) is not suitable for your application. You need to have separate images of cat's movement. Then arrow key pressed load one image.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much!  I was using a link to an older version of createjs.  I downloaded the newest version of it, and now it works with my code.  My floating cat bobs up and down, and then I can move it around with my arrow keys.  (I had made the floating cat on flash and then made a sprite sheet from it)

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that there were different versions.  Thank you so much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){throw"Ticker cannot be instantiated.";} has no method 'addEventListener'` is related to a change in the way that the Ticker object handles Event Listeners from createjs version 0.5 to createjs version 0.7.

In version 0.5 it was somehitng like this:

```
createjs.Ticker.addListener(/*function to call*/)
```

In version 0.7 it was change to

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', /*function to call*/);
```

as per [Reference](http://www.melkybee.com/blog/2013/10/11/upgrading-easeljs/) (as per problem #2)

Comment: Note that if you need to scope the callback (which was automatic in the old version of EaselJS, since it just took an object, not a function), you can use the `on()` shortcut, which accepts a `scope` parameter. It also has a handy parameter to automatically remove the listener after it is fired one time. http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_on